# How to connect docker-compose Sql server container on Docker-Linux from Windows 10?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nopcommerce

I am running my web app and sql server linux instance using docker-compose inside Linux Containers inside Windows 10. Docker-Compose file looks like as below

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    nopcommerce_web:
        build: .
        container_name: nopcommerce
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "80:80"       
        depends_on:
            - nopcommerce_database
    nopcommerce_database:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU5-ubuntu-18.04
        container_name: nopcommerceDB
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "testpassword"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"             

volumes:
  nopcommerce_data:
```

I can simply access to my website http://localhost/. But i am not able to access the sql server database using Sql Server Management Studio?

If i dont use docker-compose but only use docker file to create container. I can simply access it using `127.0.0.1, 1433`

I have tried everything. Tried to use ip address of my machine with port number etc. But it is not working. It is suggested to use `docker-machine ip` command to get ip adress of the container but docker tools are deprecated for windows.

Can someone shed some lights here? why I cannot connect to sql server but i can connect to web app?

[image]

Comment: since you are using the default port, try to use `localhost` instead of using IP and port

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the following to your docker-compose.yml:

```
expose:
 - 1433
```

Otherwise, there's no link between inside and outside of the container.